# How to get the iframe dom by an element inside it

Tags: javascript, iframe

Let's say I have an iframe element inside html:

When the content of the iframe is parsed, I can access a dom element inside it, using Javascript:

```
 var iframe = document.getElementById('ifr'),
     iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document,
     iframeElem = iframeDoc.getElementById('elementId');
```

What I want to achieve is to get back the iframe dom, only starting from an iframeElem.
I've already tried contentDocument and contentWindow property but I only get the document element and not the  element I want.
The best I could so far is this:

```
function getIframeParent(elementId) {
    let iframe;
    $('iframe').each (function() {
        iframe = this;
        let iframeDoc = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;
        if (iframeDoc.getElementById(elementId).length > 0) return;    
    });
    return iframe;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: you cannot, iframe are like a new browser tab. you can't access them by DOM commands

Comment: So, you think that the  'each loop solution' is the only one to get it?

Comment: @MisterJojo he can if iFrame is on the same domain as main document

Comment: @jigfox prove me wrong and show here a sample code of that ;-)

Comment: @MisterJojo https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp

Comment: @PaoloCirasa I can't think of any other solution than iterating over the iframes